# How do I access internal members of a union?

Tags: c++, struct, unions

I have a union that is defined like this:

```
typedef union {
  enum {
    REVISION = 0,
    CURRENT_VERSION = REVISION
  };

  enum FLAGS{
    FLAG_DEFAULT               = 0x00000000,
    FLAG_EOD                   = 0x00000001,
    FLAG_OUTOFORDER            = 0x00000002
  };

  CHAR _filler[32];

  struct INTERNAL_STRUCTURE {
    UINT16 type;
    UINT16 flags;
  };
}CORRHDR
```

How do I access the member's of INTERNAL_STRUCTURE from my code?

I've thought I could just do this:

```
CORRHDR hdr;
hdr.INTERNAL_STRUCTURE.type = 1;
```

I'm wrong. I can see the enums in the union, but nothing else. Could someone explain the structure (or benefit) of this type to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have declared the *type* called `INTERNAL_STRUCTURE`, but not an actual instance of that type. Try this:

```
typedef union {
  //...
  CHAR _filler[32];
  struct {
    UINT16 type;
    UINT16 flags;
  } INTERNAL_STRUCTURE;
}CORRHDR;
```

Then to access the field:

```
CORRHDR ch;
printf("%u\n", ch.INTERNAL_STRUCTURE.type);
```

Comment: [I'm porting from a unix system to windows]. Could defining a struct in this manner (inside the union with no instance name) just be developer reference for the binary data contained in the union?

Comment: Yes, with the declaration as given, you could access the data inside using something like: reinterpret_cast<CORRHDR::INTERNAL_STRUCTURE *>(ch._filler)->type but that seems awkward.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define an object of type `INTERNAL_STRUCTURE` before you can try to access it. Your union as of now does not have one. Try:

```
struct INTERNAL_STRUCTURE {
    UINT16 type;
    UINT16 flags;
  };
struct INTERNAL_STRUCTURE is;
```

...

Answer (score 0):

You defined a type named INTERNAL_STUCTURE

not an instance named INTERNAL_STRUCTURE.

```
typedef union {
  enum {
    REVISION = 0,
    CURRENT_VERSION = REVISION
  };

  enum FLAGS{
    FLAG_DEFAULT               = 0x00000000,
    FLAG_EOD                   = 0x00000001,
    FLAG_OUTOFORDER            = 0x00000002
  };

  CHAR _filler[32];

  struct {
    UINT16 type;
    UINT16 flags;
  } INTERNAL_STRUCTURE;
}CORRHDR;
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you define your struct but don't use it!

You need to define a variable of that struct type:

```
union Blob
{
  CHAR _filler[32];

  struct INTERNAL_STRUCTURE {
    UINT16 type;
    UINT16 flags;
  } myStruct;
};

CORRHDR hdr;
hdr.myStruct.type = 1;
```